# Viber chat bot - history on PC client is not saved

Tags: rest, chatbot, viber

We develop simple viber chat bot using rest-api. User send to bot his customer number and chatbot response with some info. On mobile devices there is no problem, but on desktop devices the history disappears after a restart. According to the documentation, there is a 24 hour session, but it refers to free messaging. We don't send bot-initiated ones, we only respond to user inquiries.